# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with Nginx & certbot

Tags: nginx, certbot

I am trying to install a webserver on Raspberry.
I installed nginx and certbot and generated SSL certificate using:
`sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /home/pi/webapp01 -d godestalbin.com -d www.godestalbin.com`
My Nginx config is now:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name godestalbin.ga www.godestalbin.ga;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/godestalbin.ga/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/godestalbin.ga/privkey.pem;

   location / {
      root /home/pi/webapp01;
   }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name godestalbin.ga;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

However, I cannot display my website in Chrome which display

```
Ce site ne peut pas fournir de connexion sécuriséewww.godestalbin.ga a envoyé une réponse incorrecte.
This site cannot provide a secure connection
www.godestalbin.ga gave an incorrect answer
Essayez d'exécuter les diagnostics réseau de Windows.
Try to execute Windows diagnostics
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

If I display locally on the raspberry my site, I can see the page (I guess because Chromium is less strict about secutiry). It also says the certificate is invalid (I guess because localhost does not match godestalbin.ga of the certificate). I am able to display the details of the certificate (see screen copy).[image]

I also take a look at the analysis given by : https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=godestalbin.ga

```
https://godestalbin.ga/
88.127.87.207
Http-Status: -4

SendFailure - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generated certbot SSL with domain : `www.godestalbin.com`

```
sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /home/pi/webapp01 -d godestalbin.com -d www.godestalbin.com
```

But you configured nginx with `server_name godestalbin.ga www.godestalbin.ga;`

Please correct them as same domain only.

Comment: When I specified both name `-d godestalbin.com -d www.godestalbin.com` is my certificate not supposed to be valid for both ?
I tried changing server_name to only `server_name www.godestalbin.ga` but I still have the same issue.
I also tried automatic installation from certbot with Nginx https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianbuster-nginx but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I meant domain .com not .ga

Comment: You're right based on the information, I provided, sorry for that. But this is a typo error when copying what I did. I actually set `-d godestalbin.ga-d www.godestalbin.ga`
We can see it in the screen copy I provided: Domain Name (CN): godestalbin.ga

Comment: Finally, I found my mistake. Nothing was wrong with certboot. The issue was in my router port redirection. I thought I should redirect 443 from outside to 80 of my server inside. After correcting 443 from outside redirected to 443 of my web server it works fine.